# DB2 SQL multiple JOIN issue

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400, rpgle

I have a query with two JOIN and it does not work. I get no errors. It just does not return any records. If I separate my query then it works. What Am I doing wrong here?

When I split up the query I get one record each which is what I should get.

Full query:

```
SELECT HPOL07.*, @RFC.*, @AAM.*
FROM BPCSPROF.HPOL07
JOIN BPCSPROF.@RFC ON PRFC = @RFC.RFCNUM  AND PPRF = @RFC.RFCPRC
 AND PGLNO = @RFC.RFCGLN
JOIN BPCSPROF.@AAM ON PPRF = @AAM.AAMPRC  AND PGLNO = @AAM.AAMGLN
WHERE PORD = '605400' AND PID <> 'PZ'
```

Separate queries:

```
 SELECT HPOL07.*, @RFC.*
    FROM BPCSPROF.HPOL07
    JOIN BPCSPROF.@RFC ON PRFC = @RFC.RFCNUM  AND PPRF = @RFC.RFCPRC
    AND PGLNO = @RFC.RFCGLN
 WHERE PORD = '605400' AND PID <> 'PZ'


SELECT HPOL07.*, @AAM.*
   FROM BPCSPROF.HPOL07
   JOIN BPCSPROF.@AAM ON PPRF = @AAM.AAMPRC  AND PGLNO = @AAM.AAMGLN
WHERE PORD = '605400' AND PID <> 'PZ'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing inner joins, so there must be a record in both @RFC and @AAM for each record in HPOL07...

Is that what you want?

If there's a matching record in @RFC or @AAM, then you'd want to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT HPOL07.*, @RFC.*, @AAM.*
FROM BPCSPROF.HPOL07
LEFT OUTER JOIN BPCSPROF.@RFC 
  ON PRFC = @RFC.RFCNUM  AND PPRF = @RFC.RFCPRC
     AND PGLNO = @RFC.RFCGLN
LEFT OUTER JOIN BPCSPROF.@AAM 
  ON PPRF = @AAM.AAMPRC  AND PGLNO = @AAM.AAMGLN
WHERE PORD = '605400' AND PID <> 'PZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

This question could certainly use a table schema but my guess is that `PGLNO` is a different value between your two joins.  If that's the case, the joins aren't going to to work because it is effectively looking for `@AAM.AAMGLN = @RFC.RFCGLN` in your current query.  This is because both joins use the `PGLNO` value and would need to be the same for both join clauses.

If you want two separate results, @Charles answer should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
SELECT * FROM A h 
   LEFT JOIN B pk ON (pk.PKKONZ='010') AND (pk.PKFIRM IN (10, 20 30)) AND h.TPPALN = pk.PKPALN 
   LEFT JOIN C ar ON (ar.TZKONZ='010') AND (ar.TZFIRM IN (55, 56 ,57)) AND h.TPIDEN = ar.TZIDEN
   WHERE ....
   ORDER BY ...
```